# How to return objects of different types from RcppArmadillo function

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

l would like to return objects of different types from the function `RcppArmadillo`.

For example, below is a code where I've tried returning both a vector and function using `std::tuple`.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <tuple>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::tuple<arma::vec, arma::mat> test_tuple(arma::vec avec, arma::mat amat) {

  arma::vec bvec = avec;
  arma::mat bmat = amat;
  return std::make_tuple(bvec, bmat);
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
static assertion failed: cannot convert type to SEXP
```

I also tried unsuccessfully using `List::create` as suggested here:

[How to return multiple objects from Rcpp back to R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177718/how-to-return-multiple-objects-from-rcpp-back-to-r)

How correctly return objects of different types and fix the above error?

Comment: You are relying on _existing infrastructure_ to automatically convert _known types_ along with a _documented ability_ to add such converters.  This is all documented -- see the vignettes as well the Rcpp Gallery.  Lastly, your subject is wrong as `std::make_tuple()` creates the return object, and that has nothing to do with (Rcpp)Armadillo.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel. I wanted to know if it is possible to return objects of different types from RcppArmadillo function. I know it is possible with Rcpp and with C++ and l tried to combine both solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "tried unsuccessfully" to use `List::create`. Does the following work for you?

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List test_tuple(arma::vec avec, arma::mat amat) {

  arma::vec bvec = avec;
  arma::mat bmat = amat;
  return Rcpp::List::create(
    Rcpp::Named("avec") = avec,
    Rcpp::Named("amat") = amat
  );
}
```

Comment: "Correct" answer in that it helps the user to return two Armadillo objects (just like, I might add, the `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` generated example does).  Incorrect in the sense that it does nothing about `std::make_tupel()`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel My take on this was that the OP wanted to return two Armadillo objects at once and was attempting to do so using tuple where it just isn't needed. I could be wrong about that of course.

Comment: Oh I am not saying it's a bad answer.  It's a fairly poor and ill-researched question though.  Maybe we should just close it.  Oh well.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron. l tried your solution and get an error `multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] no matching function for call to 'Named(int)`

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. As @DirkEddelbuettel says, this is exactly the method employed in the RcppArmadillo package skeleton demo (try creating the package skeleton, building it and testing the `rcpparma_bothproducts` function.